# How do I trigger a second click event on this toggle button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if anyone would know a good way to trigger a second click so when the toggle button switches over the colors change with it because right now you have to click the letters to switch the color and the slide bar to switch the toggle? I tried implementing the state of the toggle button so that when the state of the toggle switches the color of the text switches as well but I couldn't figure out quite how to do that. Right now the color changes through changing overlays which is basically the same text with different color onto of each other but it switches between those overlays based on which one it is currently on through a click event.

```js
function f() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("overlay");

  if (txt.className == 'overlay') {
    txt.className = "overlay2";
  } else {
    txt.className = "overlay";
  }

  var txt2 = document.getElementById("overlay2");

  if (txt2.className == 'overlay2') {
    txt2.className = "overlay";
  } else {
    txt2.className = "overlay2";
  }

  var txt3 = document.getElementById("overlay3");

  if (txt3.className == 'overlay3') {
    txt3.className = "overlay4";
  } else {
    txt3.className = "overlay4";
  }

  var txt4 = document.getElementById("overlay4");

  if (txt4.className == 'overlay4') {
    txt4.className = "overlay3";
  } else {
    txt4.className = "overlay4";
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: "Maison Neue";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 12px;
  width: 51px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay2 {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-family: "Maison Neue";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 11px;
  color: #0098CF;
  height: 12px;
  width: 51px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay3 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 108px;
  font-family: "Maison Neue";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  width: 72px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  color: #0098CF;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay4 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 108px;
  font-family: "Maison Neue";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  width: 72px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before {
  height: 31px;
  width: 193px;
  background-color: #0098CF;
  border-radius: 16.5px;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 27px;
  width: 96px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: 3px !important;
  border: 1px solid #0098CF;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 94px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>

<p> <span id="txt" class='overlay'></span></p>
<p> <span id="txt2" class='overlay2'></span></p>
<p> <span id="txt3" class='overlay3'></span></p>
<p> <span id="txt4" class='overlay4'></span></p>
<p id="overlay" onclick='f();' class="overlay"> BITS/SEC</p>
<p id="overlay2" onclick='f();' class="overlay2"> BITS/SEC</p>
<p id="overlay3" onclick='f();' class="overlay3"> PACKETS/SEC</p>
<p id="overlay4" onclick='f();' class="overlay4"> PACKETS/SEC</p>
<p id="click" onclick='f();'></p>
```

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7vk31qup/ Feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks so much that looks great appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Do you think there is anyway to do it without using jquery

Comment: Sure, here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kcjhzLrq/

Comment: i don't know if its just me but that one only works one way Chris G

Comment: Are you talking about my fiddle or your implementation?

Comment: your most recent fiddle

Comment: it only toggles one way and then once you click again to toggle it back the other way it doesn't respond to the click

Comment: thank you so much for your time btw really appreciate it

Comment: Changed line 6 to `i_c.removeAttribute("checked");` which made it work in Chrome, too. And you're welcome :)

Comment: it works omg your amazing thank you